# Is it possible to pop up my dialog box when click the close icon on the upper right corner of UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I need to add a dialog box for user's further confirmation, when users click the close icon (the cross like icon) on the upper right corner of an UWP app. But I am sure whether this is possible, and how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `confirmAppClose` capability, which is a restricted capability. If your application needs to be submitted to the Microsoft Store, you need to explain the reason for using the capability in the submission instructions.

The steps to use this capability are as follows:

**package.appxmanifest**

```xml
<Package ...
         xmlns:rescap = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
         IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

    <Capabilities>
    ...
      <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/>
    ...
    </Capabilities>

</package>
```

Listen for `CloseRequested` event in MainPage:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public MainPage():base()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested +=
        async (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Handled = true;
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Hi!");
            //TODO handle something
            App.Current.Exit();
        };
}
```

When the event is triggered, you need to set `args.Handled` to **True**, otherwise the application will still close.